# Increasing pyserial readline speed

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, cython, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to read in data sent over by an arduino. The arduino sends data over every 50 milliseconds. I have Tried receiving in 2 different formats both of which are strings. I am wondering if there is a faster way to receive this data in my python gui whether it be using a different library, receiving a different data type, or optimizing the code. 
1st Format:

```
String potcolumn = String(pot0holder) + "." + String(pot1holder) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+30) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+30) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+60) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+60) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+90) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+90) + "." +  String(i);
```

this takes on average: 0.0523106797228 seconds to read

2nd Format:

```
  pressure1 = String(pot0array[0]) + "," + String(pot0array[1]);
  displacement1 = String(pot1array[0]) + "," + String(pot1array[1]);
  iteration1 = String(i-1) + "," + String(i);
  full1 = pressure1 + ">" + displacement1 + ">" + iteration1;
  pressure2 = String(pot0array[0]+30) + "," + String(pot0array[1]+30);
  displacement2 = String(pot1array[0]+30) + "," + String(pot1array[1]+30);
  iteration2 = String(i-1) + "," + String(i);
  full2 = pressure2 + ">" + displacement2 + ">" + iteration2;
  pressure3 = String(pot0array[0]+60) + "," + String(pot0array[1]+60);
  displacement3 = String(pot1array[0]+60) + "," + String(pot1array[1]+60);
  iteration3 = String(i-1) + "," + String(i);
  full3 = pressure3 + ">" + displacement3 + ">" + iteration3;
  pressure4 = String(pot0array[0]+90) + "," + String(pot0array[1]+90);
  displacement4 = String(pot1array[0]+90) + "," + String(pot1array[1]+90);
  iteration4 = String(i-1) + "," + String(i);
  full4 = pressure4 + ">" + displacement4 + ">" + iteration4;
  fulltotal = full1 + "|" + full2 + "|" + full3 + "|" + full4;
  Serial.println(fulltotal);
```

this takes on average: 0.0937848151484 seconds to read which makes sense since it's double the data

Here is a very simple GUI to receive the data and test the read time using pyserial, tkinter, and python:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque
import random
import time
import cProfile

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=None)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.go = 0

        self.run = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Testing", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run_respiration = Tkinter.Button(self.run, text="RUN",bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run_respiration.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.test_options = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Test Options", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.test_options.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.test_options, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)


    def getData(self):
        return self.start()


    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        self.go = 0

    def start(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.go = 1
        self.timer()

    def readData(self):
        if (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):
            t = time.time()
            x = self.arduinoData.readline()
            print str(time.time()-t)# + "\t" + str(x)



    def timer(self):
        if self.go == 1:
            self.readData()
            root.after(0, self.timer)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The arduino is easily able to send the data at the correct speed it's just that the python gui isnt reading fast enough for my use.

Is it possible that it could read much faster using cython or an extension with C++ if so are there any resources that i could use as a guide I have yet to be able to find anything.

even just running this code yields an average time of .11438 seconds:

```
import time
import serial

def readData():
    if arduinoData.inWaiting()>0:
        t = time.time()
        x = arduinoData.readline()
        y = str(time.time()-t)
        print y


def run():
    x = 5000
    z = 0
    while z < x:
        readData()
        z += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=None)
    arduinoData.write("<L>")
    run()
    print('done')
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions

Comment: Are you sure it actually takes 50 milliseconds to send data? "it's just that the python gui isnt reading fast enough for my use." doesn't make sense when you don't actually use the gui to display any data and clearly isn't causing any hang ups here.  Looks like you are using python on the sending end as well.   Before you start jumping to conclusions you might want to provide more proof of your assertions.  Also what do you mean "sends data every 50 ms", do you mean per byte?

Comment: firstly i would start by profiling your python script to see where the hangup is, because that 50ms doesn't seem right. secondly, smashing strings together like that is not good for the ram in the arduino, it causes memory fragmentation which will bog it down after a few loops. instead you could have multiple `print`s for each bit (saves converting to string first and then concatenating) with the last chunk using a `println` instead

Comment: And just another note, when performance is critical, console print statements are expensive. Saving output to a file is actually faster due to buffering of the IO channel. In this way, output is actually written to a memory buffer and flushed to the disk controller as the buffer fills.

Comment: @snb I am using matplotlibs animation function to graph the data I just didn't think that was as important to show as the actual reading of the data so i didn't want to bog the post down with a bunch of extra code. I am not saying that there is something wrong with pyserial or anything else I am just asking for suggestions as to if I would be able to increase the speed at which I am reading the data. I am sending a few values over before I start reading data from the arduino I should've deleted those before i posted. The arduino is sending the string I put in the post after 50 milliseconds.

Comment: @James Kent i will change the arduino code as per your suggestion and clock it again in order to see if that has increased the speed. Thank you

Comment: @Ron Norris I will give that a try. I am not printing the data in my normal GUI i am appending them to various arrays and the using the matplotlib animation function to graph the data. I will give writing and graphing from a file a shot and see if that works any better. Thank you

Comment: changing everything to individual print statements made the read speed go from 0.0937848151484 seconds to 0.0767351 seconds

Answer (score 0):

After Profiling the above code I received this as the output

```
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 profile_stack.py:61(readData)
     1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 serialwin32.py:234(inWaiting)
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_ctypes.byref}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


      270 function calls in 0.025 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:49(create_string_buffer)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.025    0.025 profile_stack.py:61(readData)
    24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 serialutil.py:404(getTimeout)
     1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 serialwin32.py:234(inWaiting)
    24    0.023    0.001    0.024    0.001 serialwin32.py:242(read)
   146    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_ctypes.byref}
    48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.024    0.024 {method 'readline' of '_io._IOBase' objects}


      5 function calls in 0.001 seconds
```

Here is the code I used to get this information:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque
import random
import time
import cProfile

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=None)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.go = 0

        self.run = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Testing", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run_respiration = Tkinter.Button(self.run, text="RUN",bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run_respiration.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.test_options = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Test Options", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.test_options.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.test_options, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def do_cprofile(func):
        def profiled_func(*args, **kwargs):
            profile = cProfile.Profile()
            try:
                profile.enable()
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                profile.disable()
                return result
            finally:
                profile.print_stats()
        return profiled_func

    def getData(self):
        return self.start()


    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        self.go = 0

    def start(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.go = 1
        self.timer()


    @do_cprofile
    def readData(self):
        if (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):
            t = time.time()
            x = self.arduinoData.readline()
            print str(time.time()-t)# + "\t" + str(x)



    def timer(self):
        if self.go == 1:
            self.readData()
            root.after(0, self.timer)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```